# Welcome page is not displaying in servlet sample web application

Tags: java, servlets

I am new to Java Web Application Development. I am developing a small web application which involves all CRUD operations. I am unable to get the welcome file when I am running the application. Here are my files[Folder structure of dynamic web project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPRhI.png)

[url mapping an web.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoPql.png)

[Servlet for routing based urls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYP4m.png)

Comment: Please post the code rather than screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

Try by empty url string as :

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>yourHomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern> <!-- Yes, empty string! -->
</servlet-mapping>
```